# Use a Spring Boot Application as a Dependency with gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have got some trouble using a spring boot (2.1) application as dependency for an other spring boot application.

I'm aware that this is not the recommended approach, but for simplicity reasons I would like to go that route. The offical [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar) just shows how to do that with maven and not how to do that with gradle.

Project A:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.1.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

Project B:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.1.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Project A')
}
```

This however results that the application.properties (from resources) of project A are getting loaded though project b is executed.

Anyone some tips or can direct me to a working simple example?

Update:

By adding the following it works, when building the final spring boot jar. Unfortunately the problem still exists, when trying to execute it directly in Intellij.

```
jar {
  enabled= true
    exclude("**/application.properties")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that ProjectB depend on ProjectA becuase you need some common function or service ? Maybe you should extract some common module from ProjectA first. For example

```
ProjectA-common
ProjectA-app  (runnable application with application.properties)
```

Then you can import ProjectA-common as library without troule at application.properties.

If you still have to include all ProjectA , you can exclude specific configuration from properity. And write a new one to overwrite it.

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
       - com.example.config.ProjectAConfiguration
       - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: I'm aware of this and this was how it was done before. But to simplify the project for others I would like to eliminate it.

Comment: If you still have to include all ProjectA , you can exclude specific configuration from properity.

Comment: I don't think this solved the issue. The problem currently is, that the application.properties are also found form the library. I have managed to get it working when building the jar (see update in the question), but not when running it in Intellij.

Comment: There are two different way to run spring on Intellij by "IDE run" or by Gradle. So can this method run by gradle ?